# How to install the sample database used in PostgreSQL online documentation examples?

Tags: postgresql

I have installed PostgreSQL v15.3 on Oracle Linux R8-U8 (64 bits). I would like to know whether there is any particular procedure/script which permits to install the sample database including all tables/views used in PostgreSQL online documentation examples.

Just to show what I'm looking for, consider the following link to the online documentation which presents how to use scalar subqueries:

- https://www.postgresql.org/docs/16/sql-expressions.html#SQL-SYNTAX-SCALAR-SUBQUERIES

Here is the query used in the documentation:

```
SELECT name, (SELECT max(pop) FROM cities WHERE cities.state = states.name)
    FROM states;
```

The problem is that I don't have neither `states` nor `cities` tables on my local database. As a result I cannot run the online documentation examples on my own database. That's why I would like to ask whether there is any way to install all these tables/views with their corresponding data. For example in Oracle, there is a schema called HR which includes many of the tables (in particular the famous employees table) used in the documentation and there is a specific procedure to install what is required. I wonder whether the same can be achieved in PostgreSQL.

Comment: I don't know that they *are* all from a single sample DB. They are examples rather than a transcript. The pgbench tool comes with a test db though: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/pgbench.html

Comment: As far as I remember, that's in the tutorial at `src/tutorial` in the source distribution. Look at the files `basics.source` and `advanced.source`.

Comment: @ Laurenz Albe. Thank you very much for your help. I checked those files and I installed basics.sql and advanced.sql. However those table includes barely a few rows. I don't think this is something that covers the entire online examples.